# Jetpack Blog Subscriptions on Multisite

Tags: multisite, plugin-jetpack, domain

I am using Jetpack on Multisite. When I connect with WordPress, it note the MultiSite Blog Address, and uses this when a user subscribes to get emails for any posts from the site. Subscriber get confirmation email, and then get all new posts. Works well.

BUT my clients frequently have their site pointing to a Mapped Domain. To a subscriber, the multisite domain sent in the conformation email can look suspicious.

Q. Is there (or can there be) any way to cater for mapped domains in Multisite in jetpack?